# How to parse json data of type array in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

So, I am parsing this json data of type array and I have some confusion while implementing it. I have already parsed the json data of type dictionary but I don't have an idea how can I do that for an array. I am sharing the json data in array and dictionary as well.

This is the json data in dictionary:

```
{
    "daily_competition": [{
            "compitition_name": "Daily competition data",
            "logo": "daily_competition/1603792566477-burgerk.jpg",
            "description": "description",
            "start_date": "06/11/2020",
            "end_date": "06/11/2020",
            "start_time": "05:00:20 PM",
            "end_time": "08:00 PM",
            "slot_time": "9:00 AM",
            "status": "1",
            "created_by": "1",
            "modified_by": "",
            "id": "4",
            "created_at": "2020-11-06T05:20:28.109Z",
            "modified_at": ""
        },
        {
            "compitition_name": "Daily competition data 2",
            "logo": "daily_competition/1603213015955-b103005748_1.jpg",
            "description": "description",
            "start_date": "07/11/2020",
            "end_date": "07/11/2020",
            "start_time": "04:10:20 PM",
            "end_time": "05:40",
            "slot_time": "12:00 PM",
            "status": "1",
            "created_by": "1",
            "modified_by": "",
            "id": "5",
            "created_at": "2020-11-07T05:20:28.109Z",
            "modified_at": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created this handler class to get the json data:

```
class SCHandler: NSObject{
    

        class func getSCList(userName: String?, completion:@escaping (SpecialModel?, Bool, String?) -> Void){
                    
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DC", ofType: "json") {
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
                    let jsonObj = try JSON(data: data)
                    
                    
                    print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
                     let scModelObj = SpecialModel.init(fromJson: jsonObj)
                    completion(scModelObj, true, "message")
                    
                } catch let error {
                    print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Invalid filename/path.")
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the model class where I have created the properties and appended the json data in the properties.

```
class SpecialModel{

    var specialData : [SpecialData]!


    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        specialData = [SpecialData]()
        let specailArray = json["daily_competition"].arrayValue
        for specialJson in specailArray {
            let value = SpecialData(fromJson: specialJson)
            specialData.append(value)
        }
    }

}
    class SpecialData {
    
        var compititionName : String!
        var createdAt : String!
        var createdBy : Int!
        var descriptionField : String!
        var endDate : String!
        var endTime : String!
        var id : Int!
        var logo : String!
        var modifiedAt : String!
        var modifiedBy : String!
        var slotTime : String!
        var startDate : String!
        var startTime : String!
        var status : Int!
    
    
            init(fromJson json: JSON!){
            if json.isEmpty{
                return
            }
            compititionName = json["compitition_name"].stringValue
            createdAt = json["created_at"].stringValue
            createdBy = json["created_by"].intValue
            descriptionField = json["description"].stringValue
            endDate = json["end_date"].stringValue
            endTime = json["end_time"].stringValue
            id = json["id"].intValue
            logo = json["logo"].stringValue
            modifiedAt = json["modified_at"].stringValue
            modifiedBy = json["modified_by"].stringValue
            slotTime = json["slot_time"].stringValue
            startDate = json["start_date"].stringValue
            startTime = json["start_time"].stringValue
            status = json["status"].intValue
        }
    
    }
```

Now, this is the json data of type array which I want to parse:

```
[{
            "compitition_name": "Daily competition data",
            "logo": "daily_competition/1603792566477-burgerk.jpg",
            "description": "description",
            "start_date": "06/11/2020",
            "end_date": "06/11/2020",
            "start_time": "05:00:20 PM",
            "end_time": "08:00 PM",
            "slot_time": "9:00 AM",
            "status": "1",
            "created_by": "1",
            "modified_by": "",
            "id": "4",
            "created_at": "2020-11-06T05:20:28.109Z",
            "modified_at": ""
        },
        {
            "compitition_name": "Daily competition data 2",
            "logo": "daily_competition/1603213015955-b103005748_1.jpg",
            "description": "description",
            "start_date": "07/11/2020",
            "end_date": "07/11/2020",
            "start_time": "04:10:20 PM",
            "end_time": "05:40",
            "slot_time": "12:00 PM",
            "status": "1",
            "created_by": "1",
            "modified_by": "",
            "id": "5",
            "created_at": "2020-11-07T05:20:28.109Z",
            "modified_at": ""
        }
]
```

What changes do I need to make in the init method in order to parse this json data of type array. I know this is pretty simple but I am getting confused about how the parse it because I am new to swift. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `let specailArray = json["daily_competition"].arrayValue`, here you got an array there, no? use the same logic. Now, if you are using Swift4+, I'd recommend to use `Codable` instead of `SwiftyJSON`.

Comment: As I already suggested in your previous (deleted) question **do not** declare struct members and function parameters as implicit unwrapped optionals. That's a very bad and even dangerous practice.

Comment: @Larme No, I am not getting array there. I know I can use Codable here but I have to parse data without using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with what @Larme and @vadian mentioned in comments.

A small change that you can do to make your code work, is change one line in the initializer of `SpecialModel`:

```
init(fromJson json: JSON) {
    if json.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    specialData = [SpecialData]()
    let specailArray = json["daily_competition"].array ?? json.arrayValue
    for specialJson in specailArray {
        let value = SpecialData(fromJson: specialJson)
        specialData.append(value)
    }
}
```

Again, this is not ideal but will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps you to understand a way to decode your json:

```
import Foundation

extension Date {

    public static func fromString(date: String, format: String) throws -> Date {
        let dateStr = date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "bad date string \(dateStr)", code: 0)
        }

        return date
    }

    public func toString(format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

struct SpecialData: Decodable {
    var compititionName : String
    var createdAt : Date
    var createdBy : Int
    var description: String
    var endDate : Date
    var endTime : Date
    var id : Int
    var logo : String
    var modifiedAt : Date?
    var modifiedBy : String
    var slotTime : Date
    var startDate : Date
    var startTime : Date
    var status : Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case compititionName = "compitition_name"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case createdBy = "created_by"
        case description
        case endDate = "end_date"
        case endTime = "end_time"
        case id
        case logo
        case modifiedAt = "modofied_at"
        case modifiedBy = "modified_by"
        case startDate = "start_date"
        case startTime = "start_time"
        case slotTime = "slot_time"
        case status
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        compititionName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .compititionName)
        createdAt = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .createdAt), format: Self.JSONDateTimeFormat)
        createdBy = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .createdBy)
        description = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        endDate = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .endDate), format: Self.date)
        endTime = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .endTime), format: Self.time)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        logo = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .logo)
        if let modifiedAtStr = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .modifiedAt), modifiedAtStr != "" {
          modifiedAt = try Date.fromString(date: modifiedAtStr, format: Self.time)
        } else {
            modifiedAt = nil
        }
        modifiedBy = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .modifiedBy)
        startDate = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .startDate), format: Self.date)
        startTime = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .startTime), format: Self.time)
        slotTime = try Date.fromString(date: values.decode(String.self, forKey: .slotTime), format: Self.time)
        status = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
    }
    
    static let date = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    static let time = "HH:mm a"
    static let JSONDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'"
    
}

struct DailyCompletionModel: Decodable {
    let dailyCompetition: [SpecialData]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dailyCompetition = "daily_competition"
    }
}

let json: [String: Any] = [
    "compitition_name": "Daily competition data",
    "logo": "daily_competition/1603792566477-burgerk.jpg",
    "description": "description",
    "start_date": "06/11/2020",
    "end_date": "06/11/2020",
    "start_time": "05:00 PM",
    "end_time": "08:00 PM",
    "slot_time": "09:00 AM",
    "status": 1,
    "created_by": 1,
    "modified_by": "",
    "id": 4,
    "created_at": "2020-11-06T05:20:28.109Z",
    "modified_at": ""
]

let jsonData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(SpecialData.self, from: jsonData)

let jsonArray = ["daily_competition": [json, json]]
let jsonDataArray = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
print(String(data: jsonDataArray, encoding: .utf8)!)
let decodedArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(DailyCompletionModel.self, from: jsonDataArray)
print(decodedArray)
```